# Why does Montgomery Ladder not work for Brainpool curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, side-channel-attack, arithmetic

According to [SafeCurves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/ladder.html), the Brainpool curves mentioned there (P256t1 and P384t1) do not support the *Montgomery Ladder* for scalar multiplication in constant time.

I am wondering

1. why this is the case
2. if this is true for all Brainpool curves (in particular P256r1 and P512r1)

This has already partly been discussed in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/37465/38781), but no reason was stated there.

Comment: What can be confusing is that "Montgomery ladder" can also refer to [a generic algorithm](https://cr.yp.to/bib/2003/joye-ladder.pdf) which does work for Brainpool curves or any other curve

Comment: Thank you. After reading that paper, I was obviously mistaken. What I assumed to be the Montgomery ladder ist actually the generic algorithm by Joye.